# How to remove or disable before and after pseudo classes?

Tags: css, css-sprites, pseudo-class

This seems very trivial but I couldn't figure it out. Simply overriding it with `display:none` doesn't work on IE8.

```
#selector::after {
    display: none;
}
```

I am modifying a theme that's using before and after pseudo classes to add image sprites.

Comment: Double colons are used to signify pseudo-elements, not pseudo-classes. In fact, that was the entire point of introducing double colons in the first place.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use colon only one time

```
#selector:after {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C specyfication](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-selectors-20051215/#pseudo-elements) says that in *CSS3* all *pseudo-elements* like `::before` and `::after` must use the *double-colon* syntax, but:

> For compatibility with existing style sheets, user agents must also accept the previous one-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced in CSS levels 1 and 2 (namely, `:first-line`, `:first-letter`, `:before` and `:after`).

So in your case **use one-colon notation**.